# What were the requirements for the Beta badge?

Tags: support, badges

The Beta badge says it's for "active participation in the private beta."  I wonder what exactly counts as active.  Some of the people who earned it have under 150 rep, and since you start with 101 just for having an active profile on any other SE site, that's barely indicative of any participation at all.  So I wonder what the actual criteria to determine it were...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is to earn at least three bronze badges before the site hits public beta. Quite trivial, really.

Source: [Why are beta badges awarded at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/why-are-beta-badges-awarded-at-all/#comment-44251)

Comment: This is no longer accurate. Updated requirements are here: [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/300411)